# Duda en consulta MySQL

Tags: mysql

Buenos días tengo duda en esta consulta MySQL. Como primer condición quiero que el id_gral sea igual al que le mando, segunda condición que sea de un rango de fechas, tercera condición que el dst sea igual al que le mando y finalmente que de accountcode obtengo los dos últimos dígitos y quiero que sea igual al in.

La consulta está funcionando bien pero no me está trayendo datos.

```
SELECT * FROM cdr c INNER JOIN general g ON g.id_gral = 4 AND c.calldate BETWEEN '2018-02-01%' AND '2018-10-25%' AND c.dst = '175' AND right(c.accountcode, 2) = 'in';
```

Comment: creo que lo único que tienes que cambiar es esto "g.id_gral = 4" por esto "g.id_gral = c.id_gral" y al final agregar un "WHERE  g.id_gral = 4"

Answer (score 4):

Primero que nada estás teniendo un problema en la declarión de tu sentencia.

Cuando haces uso de un **INNER JOIN** buscas vincular una tabla con otra mediante sus columnas, donde los valores existan en ambas tablas, para ello haces uso del **ON** de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT*
FROM tabla1 AS a
INNER JOIN tabla2 AS b
    ON (a.campo1 = b.campo1)
```

Pero veo que en el **ON** estás ubicando tus filtros.

Lo que debes hacer es lo siguiente, entender la relación entre ambas tablas para armar correctamente el **ON**, y luego de ello usar **WHERE** para definir los filtros. Quedandote algo así:

```
SELECT*
FROM tabla1 AS a
INNER JOIN tabla2 AS b
    ON (a.campo1 = b.campo1)
WHERE a.campo1 = 'filtro1'
    AND a.campo2 BETWEEN 'filtro2' AND 'filtro3'
```

Con ello espero haberte guiado en la resolución de tu problema.

**NOTA:** te invito a que hagas un repaso de como funcionan las relaciones **INNER JOIN**, **LEFT JOIN**, **RIGHT JOIN** y **FULL OUTER JOIN**.

Answer (score 4):

Como dice @Rostan, las cuatro condiciones que requiere tu consulta deben ser incluidas como parte de un filtro `WHERE`.

La consulta es muy fácil de armar. Voy a poner tus condiciones, y las voy a ir agregando una por una en la parte del `WHERE`:

- primera condición quiero que el id_gral sea igual al que le mando, **`y`**
- segunda condición que sea de un rango de fechas, **`y`**
- tercera condición que el dst sea igual al que le mando  **`y`**
- finalmente que de accountcode obtengo los dos últimos dígitos y quiero que sea igual al in.

Construimos la consulta:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (falta indicar la forma en que se relacionan las tablas)
WHERE 
    g.id_gral=4 AND                                             -- 1ª condición
    c.calldate BETWEEN '2018-02-01%' AND '2018-10-25%' AND      -- 2ª condición 
    c.dst = '175'  AND                                          -- 3ª condición 
    right(c.accountcode, 2) = 'in'                              -- 4ª condición
```

Como ves, la consulta queda en el aire en la parte del `FROM`, ya que te queda una condición a definir o más bien, falta contextualizar el diseño de datos: **cómo se relacionan las tablas**.

Imaginemos un contexto: tengo una tabla `general` que se relaciona con una tabla `cuenta` mediante la columna `id_gral`.

Con esa información de contexto, ya podemos completar la parte del `FROM` de la consulta, y en consecuencia la consulta completa:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    general g INNER JOIN cuenta c ON g.id_gral=c.id_gral        -- información que faltaba
WHERE 
    g.id_gral=4 AND                                             -- 1ª condición
    c.calldate BETWEEN '2018-02-01%' AND '2018-10-25%' AND      -- 2ª condición 
    c.dst = '175'  AND                                          -- 3ª condición 
    right(c.accountcode, 2) = 'in'                              -- 4ª condición
```

Por cierto, nunca había visto el uso de `%` en las condiciones de `BETWEEN`.  ¿Eso sirve para algo?

Comment: Muy bien explicado @A. Cedano.